# AppCenter Android build problems

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-pipelines, build.gradle, visual-studio-app-center

I'm having some troubles with my current Android build in App Center. The APK signs fine (picture below)

[image: image apk]

But i'm having troubles getting the .aab needed for the my first Play Store release. It says: "No matching files were found with search pattern..."

[image: image-aab]

I've activated in App Center the option to build and sign the .aab

[image]

Do I need to specify something in my build.gradle to get the .aab file?

Comment: Looks like you're building an APK, not AAB

Comment: @spartygw question updated

Comment: Do you actually create an app bundle? What does your build script do? Check out the differences in generating an APK and a bundle: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#build_bundle

Comment: Can you share build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue to staging env for testing turning off the toggle for app bundle it solved in my case only apk is needed for testers [bundle toggle turn off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qhdk.png)